# SQL to MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

I like to implement

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
    WHERE 
         name like '$query_string' or 
         title like '%$query_string%' or 
         tags like '%$query_string%'"
```

to mongoDB, and I tried

```
$condition = array('$or' => 
   array('writer'=> array('name'=>"$query_string"), 
          'title'=> new MongoRegex("/$query_string/"),  
          'tags' => new MongoRegex("/$query_string/") ));
```

and this does not work.

What is proper way to implement that SQL to mongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I construct a case-insensitive, "contains" term

```
$containsTerm = new MongoRegex(sprintf('/%s/i', preg_quote($term, '/')));
```

So your condition might look like

```
$condition = array('$or' => array(
    'writer.name' => $term,
    'title'       => $containsTerm,
    'tags'        => $containsTerm
));
```

Apologies if the condition array is wrong, I typically use the [Doctrine ODM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb_odm)

Comment: I did not know I can query like 'writer.name' instead of 'writer'=> array('name'=>"$query_string"). Pretty Impressive!

Comment: @JeongWooChang See the section titled "Arrays" near the bottom - http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php

Comment: @JeongWooChong Which part doesn't work? How does it "not work"?

Comment: I'm trying to break down my problems... I found out that using array does not work but 'writer.name' way works!